# Converting a number to duration ( days, hours minutes and seconds)

Tags: sql

Do you know how to convert this duration number 145351401 to days, hours, minutes and seconds in SQL?

I tried
`SELECT CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(cast(145351401 as varchar),3,0,':'),6,0,':'),9,0,'.') AS TIME)`

but it gave me the hours, minutes and seconds but no days.

The above number is the difference between the below two dates, so it should have something like 7 days and the hours, minutes and seconds in the duration.

```
2022-09-08 16:21:48.400
2022-09-16 07:22:31.400
```

Comment: Is that number seconds?

Comment: The *seconds* between those two dates is 658843, so what does your number represent?

Comment: @NickW   thanks. I'm honestly not sure. It's supposed to represent the difference between these two date and time stamps:

2022-09-08 16:21:48.400
2022-09-16 07:22:31.400

This number was provided by a vendor as being the difference between these two dates. Another option is if you can help me to calculate the difference between the two dates in days, hours, minutes and seconds. I would still be curious to convert the above number to the same, though. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks, @Stu 

I'm honestly not sure. It's supposed to represent the difference between these two date and time stamps: 2022-09-08 16:21:48.400 2022-09-16 07:22:31.400 This number was provided by a vendor as being the difference between these two dates. Another option is if you can help me to calculate the difference between the two dates in days, hours, minutes and seconds. I would still be curious to convert the above number to the same, though. Thanks so much!

Comment: I tried this, but it only gave me 0 Days 0 Hours 3 Minutes 3 Seconds.
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2022-09-08 16:21:48.400','2022-09-16 07:22:31.400') / 86400 )) + ' Days '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2022-09-08 16:21:48.400','2022-09-16 07:22:31.400') % 86400 ) / 3600 )) + ' Hours '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2022-09-08 16:21:48.400','2022-09-16 07:22:31.400') % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ))+ ' Minutes ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2022-09-08 16:21:48.400','2022-09-16 07:22:31.400') % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60 ))+ ' Seconds';